# MaxRequestLength Vs MaxReceivedMessageSize

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Could anyone please tell me what is the exact difference between maxRequestLength and maxReceivedMessageSize? From MSDN, it seems both are used to specify the limit of the message that can be received.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1653299.aspx?maxRequestLength+in+WCF+

Comment: Thanks Sebastian! It helps. So should we conclude that maxRequestLength dicates for the request from client to service and maxReceivedMessageSize dictates for the response from service to client (irrespective of streamed or buffered messages) ?